# Android - FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, camera, photo

error:

```
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20140728_190726_1641148246.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

But I can see file in `F:\Pictures\JPEG_20140728_190726_1641148246.jpg` (mobile storage)

Im using methods from [Taking Photos Simply | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), but if u need see code, I can copy here

I also added permsissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

All what I want is take picture using camera intent, save image, save path to database and then show it on map ...

Im testing on android 4.4.2 (CM)

Comment: Try creating a test file somewhere on your computer and then doing an "adb push testFile /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/" to see where it goes in the Windows file system. The path you are looking at might not be the path the system is looking at.

Answer (score 4):

From the example you had:

```
mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
```

just try to use:

```
mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Somehow removing "file:" worked for me even though that is the example the official developer docs had.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURE‌​S) + "/JPEG_20140728_190726_1641148246.jpg");
```

instead?

Comment: for saving? im loading image using `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions); imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Comment: the try imagePath=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURE‌​S) + "/JPEG_20140728_190726_1641148246.jpg"

Comment: `E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Pictures/JPEG_20140728_190726_1641148246.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this problem exists but I figured how to avoid it. Try changing:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

To

```
try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { }
```

And it will work with no problem.

PS. I was fallowing the same android developer guide and faced the same problem as you.